# No space left on device error when pulling image from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I am pulling Docker images from AWS, but am getting the following error:

> ERROR: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob140995455: no space left on device

I have pruned the system and tried removing all containers and images, but still no luck. I can pull some images but after a small number of them I get the error.

Does anyone have a clear idea of what this could be?

Comment: Check free space for the filesystem, where is folder `/var/lib/docker/`.

Comment: builder  buildkit  containers  image  network  overlay2  plugins  runtimes  swarm  tmp trust  volumes

Comment: I can't get into the directories however, even with sudo

Comment: It is a temporary directory, that is why you cannot see it. just check the space by running:

    df -h /var/lib/docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the amount of disk space used by typing this command:

```
du -h
```

Sometimes the Docker images are being copied to a limited disk partition, in which case you can probably expand it, but I haven't tried that myself.